# Printing in Openlayers 3 (pdf)

Tags: openlayers-3

I have made a printing tools for openlayers 3 which prints in PDF format. Here is my code to print in pdf.

```
var dims = {
  a0: [1189, 841],
  a1: [841, 594],
  a2: [594, 420],
  a3: [420, 297],
  a4: [297, 210],
  a5: [210, 148]
  };

  var exportElement = document.getElementById('export-pdf');

  exportElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  if (exportElement.className.indexOf('disabled') > -1) {
    return;
  }
  exportElement.className += ' disabled';

  var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
  var resolution = document.getElementById('resolution').value;
  var buttonLabelElement = document.getElementById('button-label');
  var label = buttonLabelElement.innerText;
  var dim = dims[format];
  var width = Math.round(dim[0] * resolution / 25.4);
  var height = Math.round(dim[1] * resolution / 25.4);
  var size = /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize());
  var extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(size);

  map.once('postcompose', function(event) {
    //var tileQueue = map.getTileQueue();

    // To prevent potential unexpected division-by-zero
    // behaviour, tileTotalCount must be larger than 0.

    //var tileTotalCount = tileQueue.getCount() || 1;
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      //var tileCount = tileQueue.getCount();
      //var ratio = 1 - tileCount / tileTotalCount;
      //buttonLabelElement.innerText = ' ' + (100 * ratio).toFixed(1) + '%';
      //if (ratio == 1 && !tileQueue.getTilesLoading()) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        buttonLabelElement.innerText = label;
        var canvas = event.context.canvas;
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', undefined, format);
        pdf.addImage(data, 'JPEG', 0, 0, dim[0], dim[1]);
        pdf.save('map.pdf');
        map.setSize(size);
        map.getView().fitExtent(extent, size);
        map.renderSync();
        exportElement.className =
            exportElement.className.replace(' disabled', '');
     // }
    }, 100);
  });

  map.setSize([width, height]);
  map.getView().fitExtent(extent, /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize()));
  map.renderSync();

}, false);
```

I can print in PDF when I have only OSM Layer but when I add local layers from my geoserver I can't print anything and the whole application is freezed.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I am using jspdf to print pdf.

AJ

Comment: Any error messages in the console? Do you set the crossOrigin option on your OSM/geoserver layers?

Comment: I get "SecurityError: The operation is insecure. printmap.js:45:0" 
var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); this line

I haven't sent anything on my OSM/geoserver layers.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you load imagery from other domains, and haven't configured them for CORS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image for a description on cross origin image use.

In order to get data out of the canvas, all images put into it must be from the same domain or transmitted with the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

I would investigate how to set up your server to serve the map imagery with those headers. You should also take a look at the `crossOrigin` option on your ol3 sources.

Comment: thanks. i will have a look at it too. i hope u can help me to solve this issue

Comment: Ajaya i was wondering if you have solved the problem ? i am stuck on the same problem i added the cross origin filter in my geoserver but still its not working any help from any one ?

Comment: Yes I was able to solve the issue. Do you still need help @Abhijit Gujar ??

Comment: Yes , I would like to know. Thanks .

Comment: Wow, I just ran into this issue. Was skeptical that CORS would be the culprit for a printing issue, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

There is few solutions for CORS.
Very simple solution is to proxy OSM requests through your backend server (user <-> backend <-> OSM), but then we have little more server load.